# React Material-UI TextInput with fixed text along with placeholder

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to achieve the below UI for TextInput. It should have a fixed text at end along with a placeholder where the input can be given.

[image]

Note: the Fixed text shouldn't be editable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Docs on input adornments: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#input-adornments

```js
import { TextField, InputAdornment } from "@material-ui/core";

<TextField
    placeholder="00"
    InputProps={{
        endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">km</InputAdornment>,
    }}
/>
```